# Python exec with a function chain producing NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-exec

Consider the following script, which uses `exec` to define two functions, one of which calls the other:

```
def run_code():
  code = """
def foo():
  print('foo')
  return 1

def bar():
  print('bar calls foo')
  return 1 + foo()

result = bar()
"""

  exec(code, globals(), locals())
  print('Result: {}'.format(locals()['result']))

run_code()
```

I would expect to see the following output:

```
bar calls foo
foo
Result: 2
```

but instead, I get the following output+stacktrace:

```
bar calls foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal.py", line 17, in <module>
    run_code()
  File "minimal.py", line 14, in run_code
    exec(code, globals(), locals())
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in bar
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Interestingly, if the content of `run_code` is moved into the module level, then it works fine. However, if I then replace `globals()` or `locals()` with a new empty dictionary, it breaks once again. I also know that putting `def foo` inside `bar`'s body will make it work.

Why is this error occurring, and what is the proper fix?

(I know that `exec` is generally frowned upon. I am using it for good reason.)

Comment: Modifying `locals()` is undefined behavior, and you're doing that here.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica If I replace `locals()` and `globals()` with new empty dictionaries, the issue persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If provided, locals can be any mapping object. Remember that at module
> level, globals and locals are the same dictionary. If exec gets two
> separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as
> if it were embedded in a class definition.

And class definitions *do not create enclosing scope*, note, this is why you cannot call a method from another method without using `self`. So *just* pass the `globals()` dictionary. Or pass two of the same dict's to both arguments.

```
In [4]: def run_code():
   ...:     code = """
   ...: def foo():
   ...:   print('foo')
   ...:   return 1
   ...:
   ...: def bar():
   ...:   print('bar calls foo')
   ...:   return 1 + foo()
   ...:
   ...: result = bar()
   ...: """
   ...:     namespace = {}
   ...:     exec(code, namespace)
   ...:     print('Result: {}'.format(namespace['result']))
   ...:

In [5]: run_code()
bar calls foo
foo
Result: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
code = """  
def foo():
  print('foo')
  return 1

def bar():
  global foo;
  print('bar calls foo')
  return 1 + foo()

result = bar()
"""
def run_code():
    exec(code, globals(), locals())
    print('Result: {}'.format(locals()['result']))


run_code()
```

Output:

```
bar calls foo
foo
Result: 2
```

Comment: wait, what the heck - `global` is not supposed to work like that.

Comment: I think this is actually a bug. `global foo` inside `bar` is causing `def foo()` to store `foo` in globals instead of locals, but that `global` declaration is only supposed to affect assignments to `foo` inside `bar`.